# Testing Haskell code defined in the Main module

Tags: haskell, testing, cabal

I'm looking for help regarding how to write tests for Haskell code that is defined in the Main module.

The project I want to test is a cabal package in which I've defined multiple executables.
Each executable code is declared only made of a single file (one for each project euler problem), and I usually run them individually with the `cabal run` command.

I have tried to write a test, also in the Main module, but when compiling, the function I'm trying to test is not found ("Not in scope" error).

What is the right way to write tests in this case?

For information, below is the directory layout of my project:

```
pe/                     # root
  pe.cabal
  src/
    Util.hs
    Problem001.hs       # "module Main where" and declares a main function
    Problem002.hs       # "module Main where" and declares a main function
    (...)
  test/
    TestProblem001.hs   # "module Main where" and declares a main function
```

Below is an extract from pe.cabal:

```
test-suite test-all
    hs-source-dirs:      test
    type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:             TestProblem001.hs
    build-depends:       base, HUnit, Cabal >= 1.9.2

executable problem-001
    hs-source-dirs:      src
    main-is:             Problem001.hs
    build-depends:       base
    ghc-options:         -Wall -Werror -O2
```

[edit]

As I couldn't find any resource for this exact requirement, I opted for a project architecture which is easier to test: problems are defined as library and not individual executables anymore.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the package defined in ``pe.cabal`` to your ``build-depends`` for the ``test-all`` test suite.

Comment: Do you mean adding `problem-001` to the `build-depends` of `test-all`?
I think I tried that and got a parsing error (maybe on `-`), but I'll try again.

Comment: If you use ``problem-001`` as the ``name`` of your cabal package that would cause a parse error, it's an invalid package name. ``problem001`` is ok though. The last line would then read:
``build-depends:  problem001, base, HUnit, Cabal >= 1.9.2``

Comment: "Cabal package names can use letters, numbers and hyphens"
(http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html)
Is it a different problem?

Comment: When I change `problem-001` to `problem001` and add it to `test-all` dependencies, I get the following error: "cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
problem001 -any"

Answer (score -5):

I do so

```
test1 = ...
test2 = ...
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
       ... -> check test1
       ... -> check test2
```